# Sending JavaScript String Array to PHP Web service

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, web-services, mysqli

I am trying to send a JavaScript String Array (`arrayItems`) to a PHP Web service in order to send a query to a MySQL database. Nonetheless, no data is returned from the Web service. Data is only correctly returned from the Web service when the JavaScript String Array has only 1 item.

*The Web service is in PHP 5.6.30.*

Sample of HTML to display the data returned:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in arrayInfo track by $index">ID: {{ item.idFruit }}, 
name: {{ item.name_fruit }}</li>
</ul>
```

Sample of the `Ctrl` controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'services', Ctrl]);

function Ctrl($scope, services) {
    var arrayItems = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
    services.getInfo(arrayItems).then(function(data){
       $scope.arrayInfo = data.data;
    });
};
```

Sample of the app.js to send request to the Web service:

```
.factory('services', ['$http', function($http){
    var serviceBase = 'services/';
    var obj = {};
    obj.getInfo = function (arrayItems) {
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'get_info?arrayItems=' + arrayItems);
    };
    // return obj
    return obj;
}]);
```

Sample of the Web service in PHP:

```
private function get_info(){
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
        $this->response('', 406);
    }
    $arrayItems = (array)$this->_request['arrayItems'];
    $fruits = implode("','", $arrayItems);
    $query = "SELECT idFruit, name_fruit FROM Table_Fruits WHERE name_fruit IN 
('$fruits')";
    $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($r->num_rows > 0){
        $result = array();
        while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        $this->response($this->json($result), 200); // send user details
    }
    $this->response('', 204);   // send user detail
}
```

Thank you *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Meanwhile, I solve my own question.**

There is the solution if someone needs it in the future:

*(Problem: the JavaScript String Array was badly converted to a PHP String Array in my question)*

Solution:

```
 private function get_info(){
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
      $this->response('', 406);
    }
    $arrayItems = $this->_request['arrayItems'];

    //Explode on comma
    $vals = explode(',', $arrayItems);
    //Trim whitespace
    foreach($vals as $key => $val) {
      $vals[$key] = trim($val);
    }
    //Return empty array if no items found
    //http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#114273
    $arrayItems_php = array_diff($vals, array(""));

    $fruits = implode("','", $arrayItems_php);
    $query = "SELECT idFruit, name_fruit FROM Table_Fruits WHERE name_fruit 
    IN ('$fruits')";
        $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);


   if($r->num_rows > 0){
      $result = array();
      while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
        $result[] = $row;
      }
      $this->response($this->json($result), 200); // send user details
    }
    $this->response('', 204);   // send user detail
  }
```